# Java Enhanced For Loop

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, foreach

How would I write the following for loop using an enhanced for loop>

```
    int [] info = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};

      int i;
      for (i = 0; i < info.length; i++) {
             if ((i+1) % 10 == 0)
                      System.out.println(info[i]);
             else
                      System.out.println(info[i] + ", ");
      }
```

I am trying the following, but i guess im doing it incorreclty

```
for(int i: info){
   body here///
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your syntax is correct. The difference is only that you're assigning the **actual int value** to `i` instead of the loop index. Thus, if you replace `(i+1) % 10` by `i % 10` and `info[i]` by `i`, it will work correctly.

```
int[] info = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
for (int i : info) {
    if (i % 10 == 0)
        System.out.println(i);
    else
        System.out.println(i + ", ");
}
```

To learn more about the enhanced for loop, check [this Sun guide](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html).

The above can by the way be shortened with help of the [ternary operator](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html) ;)

```
int[] info = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
for (int i : info) {
    System.out.println(i + (i % 10 == 0 ? "" : ", "));
}
```

Comment: the original and new versions of the code do subtly different things; e.g. change the last element of `info` to `11` and see what happens.

Comment: @Stephen: tell that to his tutor.