# Return an array with all negatives in a matrix

Tags: java, arrays, matrix

I am new to programming and want to establish good habits, could I have done this in another and faster way?

```
int[] getNegatives(int[][] m) {
    int countNegatives = 0; // used to create length of array
    for (int i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m[i].length; j++) {
            if (m[i][j] < 0) {
                countNegatives += 1;
            }
        }
    }
    int[] arr = new int[countNegatives];
    int increase = 0; // used to increment index of array
    for (int i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m[i].length; j++) {
            if (m[i][j] < 0) {
                arr[increase] = m[i][j];
                increase += 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: You can use an arraylist which is basically a dynamic array that increases in size when needed, using that you just need to traverse the 2d array once.

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ may be a better place for this question.

Answer (score 2):

You could use an [ArrayList](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_arraylist.asp) instead of an array. That way you don't need to know the exact number before creating the array, and you can skip the counting.
You would need to use Integer though since you cant put primitives in Java Collections.

```
List<Integer> getNegatives(int[][] m) {
    List<Integer> negatives = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int[] ints : m) {
        for (int anInt : ints) {
            if (anInt < 0) {
                negatives.add(anInt);
            }
        }
    }
    return negatives;
}
```

If you really don't want to use Collections you can still improve your code by using the [enhanced for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2330891/java-enhanced-for-loop)

```
int[] getNegatives(int[][] m) {
    int countNegatives = 0;
    for (int[] ints : m) {
        for (int anInt : ints) {
            if (anInt < 0) {
                countNegatives += 1;
            }
        }
    }
    int[] arr = new int[countNegatives];
    int increase = 0;
    for (int[] ints : m) {
        for (int anInt : ints) {
            if (anInt < 0) {
                arr[increase++] = anInt;
            }
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
```